# Documents read per user per day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
user_id    document_id    date
------------------------------------
1           1             2016-01-01
1           2             2016-01-01
1           3             2016-01-02
2           4             2016-01-01
2           5             2016-01-02
3           6             2016-01-02
3           7             2016-01-02
3           8             2016-01-02
3           9             2016-01-03
3          10             2016-01-03
3          11             2016-01-04
3           9             2016-01-04
```

I would like to have an overview: (a) for each day in the table (b) how many documents have been read per user, as follows:

```
date          user_id    document_count
---------------------------------------
2016-01-01    1          2
2016-01-01    2          1
2016-01-01    3          0
2016-01-02    1          1
2016-01-02    2          1
2016-01-02    3          3
2016-01-03    1          0
2016-01-03    2          0
2016-01-03    3          2
2016-01-04    1          0
2016-01-04    2          0
2016-01-04    3          2
```

I only know how to get a result like (1) documents per day or (2) users per day by grouping by date and do a count on the other. But here I have to group by user AND date, and I don't know how to do this.

For learning purposes, how could I achieve also the following, related, result? It would probably require a different grouping order, but I am unsure.

```
user_id    date         document_count
--------------------------------------
1          2016-01-01   1
1          2016-01-02   1
1          2016-01-03   0
1          2016-01-04   0
2          2016-01-01   1
2          2016-01-02   1
2          2016-01-03   0
2          2016-01-04   0
3          2016-01-01   0
3          2016-01-02   3
3          2016-01-03   2
3          2016-01-04   2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: . . Your second result looks like the first results, just ordered differently -- `order by user_id, date` rather than `order by date, user_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky, because of the "0" counts.  That is, you want an output row where you have no inputs.

Your question explicitly states that you only care about the dates are in the data.  That is convenient -- there is no need to generate dates.

The first step is to generate all the output rows, using `CROSS JOIN`.  The second is to use `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY` to get the information you want:

```
select d.date, t.user_id, count(*)
from (select distinct date from t) d cross join
     (select distinct user_id from t) u left join
     t
     on t.date = d.date and t.user_id = u.user_id
group by d.date, t.user_id
order by d.date, t.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check following SELECT script

```
/*
create table UserDocuments (user_id int, document_id int, [date] date)
insert into UserDocuments values 
(1,           1,             '2016-01-01'),
(1,           2,             '2016-01-01'),
(1,           3,             '2016-01-02'),
(2,           4,             '2016-01-01'),
(2 ,          5,             '2016-01-02'),
(3,           6,             '2016-01-02'),
(3,           7,             '2016-01-02'),
(3,           8,             '2016-01-02'),
(3,           9,             '2016-01-03'),
(3,          10,             '2016-01-03'),
(3,          11,             '2016-01-04'),
(3,           9 ,            '2016-01-04')
*/

select
    [date], [user_id], count(*) document_count
from UserDocuments
group by [date], [user_id]
order by [date], [user_id]
```

Hello,
I have updated the above SELECT with addition of a DATES table
Please check below SQL script

```
declare @date_begin date = '20160101'
declare @date_end date = '20160105'

;WITH CTE_DatesTable
AS
(
  SELECT @date_begin AS [date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
  FROM CTE_DatesTable
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= @date_end
)
SELECT 
    d.[date], u.[user_id], count(ud.user_id) document_count
FROM CTE_DatesTable d
CROSS JOIN tblUsers u
LEFT JOIN UserDocuments ud
    on d.date = ud.[date] and ud.user_id = u.[user_id]
group by d.[date], u.[user_id]
order by d.[date], u.[user_id]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

You can check SQL tutorial how to [create dates table in SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-dates-table-using-tsql-cte-calendar-table.aspx) using recursive CTE expression if you want to get details of date table creation for your case

Comment: This not working, because with this script you don't receive entries for users, that haven't read a document at a day.

Comment: I've updated the script by adding a SQL Dates table in the FROM clause of the SELECT statement, thank you schlonzo for reminding me about the dates consideration